# React native, invalid attempt to spread non inerrable instance

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

Getting error while posting something:- Invalid attempt to spread non-inerrable instance.
In order to be inerrable, non-array objects must have a Symbol. Iterator method.

I think it's occur in add Post but don't why it's occur. Can someone please tell me why?
I don't know what cause error or why

here is my code

```
class Home extends Component {
  state = {
    modal: false,
    post: [
      {
        key: "1",
        title: "A Good Boi",
        des: "He's a good boi and every one know it.",
        image: require("../assets/dog.jpg"),
      },
      {
        key: "2",
        title: "John Cena",
        des: "As you can see, You can't see me!",
        image: require("../assets/cena.jpg"),
      },
    ],
  };

  addPost = (posts) => {
    posts.key = Math.random().toString();
    this.setState((prevState) => {
      return {
        post: [...prevState.posts, posts],
        modal: false,
      };
    });
  };

  closeModal = () => {
    this.setState({ modal: false });
  };

  deleteItem = (item) => {
    Alert.alert("Delete", "Are You Sure?", [
      {
        text: "Yes",
        onPress: () =>
          this.setState({
            post: this.state.post.filter((p) => p.key !== item.key),
          }),
      },
      { text: "no" },
    ]);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <Screen style={styles.screen}>
        <Modal visible={this.state.modal} animationType="slide">
          <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={Keyboard.dismiss}>
            <View style={styles.modalContainer}>
             
              <AddPost addPost={this.addPost} />
            </View>
          </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
        </Modal>
        <FlatList
          data={this.state.post}
          renderItem={({ item }) => (
            <>
             
              <Card
                title={item.title}
                subTitle={item.des}
                image={item.image}
                onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate("Details", item)}
              />
            </>
          )}
        />

        <FloatButton
          name="plus"
          onPress={() => this.setState({ modal: true })}
        />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `addPost` you have

```
// the previousState is initialized with post, not posts
post: [...prevState.posts, posts]
```

but what you likely meant is

```
post: [...prevState.post, posts]
```

Overall your naming seems to be confusing. If the state holds a list of posts clearly the property should be named `posts` instead of just `post`.
Your `addPost` function suggests that it takes a single post as an argument but then you name the parameter `posts` instead of just `post`. You should change it to look like this:

```
state = {
    modal: false,
    posts: [ /* ... */ ],
};

addPost = post => {
    post.key = Math.random().toString();
    this.setState((prevState) => {
        return {
            posts: [...prevState.posts, post],
            modal: false,
        };
    });
};
```

Comment: thnk you so much i'm working from morning i think i should rest instead of making spelling mistakes